# How to unshelve changes using git-p4

Tags: git, perforce, git-p4

Latest git-p4 script (https://github.com/ermshiperete/git-p4) has a "shelve" but no "unshelve" command. 
How do I unshelve changes using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like you can, though `git p4`, instead you'll need to do it through Perforce.

Answer (score 3):

Since Git 2.18 (Q2 2018), there is a [`git p4 unshelve` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4/2.18.0#_unshelve)

> Unshelving will take a shelved P4 changelist, and produce the equivalent `git commit` in the branch `refs/remotes/p4/unshelved/<changelist>`.

But it was flawed:

The "`unshelve`" subcommand of "[`git p4`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9f4588d72b035714d4524342479e375742ac05b3/Documentation/git-p4.txt#L174)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4#_unshelve))</sup>" used incorrectly used `commit^N` where it meant to say `commit~N` to name the `N`<sup>th</sup> generation ancestor, which has been corrected with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020).

See [commit 0acbf59](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0acbf5997fa26747aec544d2ef6a27e4feb75e81), [commit 677fa8d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/677fa8d1157c869974355e316d0e2349759d0325) (19 Sep 2020) by [Luke Diamand (`ldiamand42`)](https://github.com/ldiamand42).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9f4588d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f4588d72b035714d4524342479e375742ac05b3), 25 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`git-p4 unshelve`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/677fa8d1157c869974355e316d0e2349759d0325): adding a commit breaks `git-p4 unshelve`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Luke Diamand</sup>

> `git-p4 unshelve` uses `HEAD^$n` to find the parent commit, which fails if there is an additional commit.